# SQLite: Combining 'WHERE' conditions

Tags: sql, sqlite

A question for my general understanding: 
If I have:

```
SELECT X, Y, Z FROM MyTable
```

and I want only entries where none of the values are null I have to use

```
SELECT X, Y, Z FROM MyTable 
WHERE X IS NOT NULL AND Y IS NOT NULL AND Z IS NOT NULL
```

Is there a shorter option? Something like

```
SELECT X, Y, Z FROM MyTable 
WHERE X, Y, Z IS NOT NULL
```

This is just a short example, but I guess in queries with many conditions and requests something like this could make the query string much shorter and more readable.

Comment: Not really.  The first method is quite sensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such shorter form than below query.

```
SELECT X, Y, Z 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE X IS NOT NULL AND Y IS NOT NULL AND Z IS NOT NULL
```